# Multiple proportion test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, controlling-for-a-variable

I want to test which week day is more important for a specific client, given a historical communication in different days and with open email or not . for example:

|  | monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| email | 40 | 60 | 34 | ... |
| open | 20 | 40 | 13 | ... |
| proportion | 20/40 | 40/60 | 13/34 | ... |

First I want to test all the days at the same time and know which one is the most important day. Any sugestions?

HO: Proportion_monday = Proportion_all_days (but all the same times)

H1: Proportion_monday > Proportion_all_days

Comment: Do you have a sense of what your null and alternative hypotheses would be? If you cannot phrase them in terms of math, perhaps you can phrase them in English that the community can help you translate into math.

Comment: Could you tell us what those numbers mean, how they were calculated, and about the data they might be based on?

Comment: Dave  and @whuber I tried to explain in a better way, sorry for my english.

Comment: You don't need a test for this: if "more important" corresponds to "higher rate of opening," just identify the day with the greatest opening rate.  It can be useful to construct confidence limits around those rates so you can determine which of the lower-rate days, if any, are significantly worse than the best day.